# Mac Terminal view is Screen Sharing is Enabled

Tags: mac, terminal, remote-desktop, plist, apple-remote-desktop

Is there a way to use Terminal to check to see if Screen Sharing/Remote Desktop is enabled? Or is there a file which will have a YES/NO of it?

The one catch; it must work without sudo or admin privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do so by checking for the existence of the launchd files in /etc:

```
[[ -f /etc/RemoteManagement.launchd ]] && echo 'enabled' || echo 'disabled'
```

or for screen sharing:

```
[[ -f /etc/com.apple.screensharing.agent.launchd ]] && echo 'enabled' || echo 'disabled'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `rfb` port is opened (5900) with:

```
netstat -atp tcp | grep rfb
```

Comment: That will show if Screen Sharing is running, but not Remote Management.