# Is there a Terminal command to verify macOS screensharing?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen-sharing, perl

Is there a terminal command to determine if a screensharing session from a remote machine is not just initiated but also actively being viewed?

Details:

I have a background (Perl) process running on a remote machine that issues system commands like

```
netstat -n | grep 5900
ps aux | grep ScreensharinAgent
```

to verify that a Screensharing session has been initiated. Both of these commands return expected data the moment Screensharing authentication begins.

However, I'd also like the process to determine if the screen is successfully being viewed.

[da4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9380/da4)'s [comment here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58820/how-to-know-if-mac-os-x-machine-is-being-remotely-viewed#comment347842_58820) comes close but I can't/don't know how to modularize `log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Authentication"'`.

Here's a modified version of the Perl snippet I'm working on

```
$owner = "owner"
$user = trim(`stat -f%Su /dev/console`);

while ($user eq $owner) {
my $user = trim(`stat -f%Su /dev/console`);
my %screensharing_processes = (
    "netstat -n | grep 5900" => "\.5900.*?ESTABLISHED",
    "ps aux | grep ScreensharingAgent" => "$user.*?ScreensharingAgent.bundle",
    "terminal_command_to_verify_screensharing" => "some_string_verifying_condition",
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  );
  while (($command, $value) = each (%screensharing_processes)) {
    my $this_process = `$command`;
    if ($this_process =~ /$value/s) {
      print "$value is up\n";
    } else {
      print "$value is down\n";
    }
  }
  print "\n";
  sleep 1;
}

sub trim {
  return $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//rg;
}
```

Is there a terminal command which the remote machine's background process can issue to determine if the screensharing session is not just initiated but also actively being viewed?

For obvious reasons, solutions like the accepted one in [the question I mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58820/how-to-know-if-mac-os-x-machine-is-being-remotely-viewed) won't work here.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152303/mac-terminal-view-is-screen-sharing-is-enabled has good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s been a minute since [Günter Zöchbauer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/238346/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) helpfully [commented](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307733/is-there-a-terminal-command-to-verify-macos-screensharing#comment528911_307733) that [Mac Terminal view is Screen Sharing is Enabled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152303/mac-terminal-view-is-screen-sharing-is-enabled) "has good answers".

There, [Mateusz Szlosek](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/74657/mateusz-szlosek) [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152303/mac-terminal-view-is-screen-sharing-is-enabled#comment179213_152306)

```
netstat -atp tcp | grep rfb
```

will return the status of `rfb` port 5900.

In macOS Monterey 12.6.1, issuing `netstat -atp tcp | grep rfb` will return a line that ends with `ESTABLISHED` if Screensharing is being actively viewed. For example:

```
┕ netstat -atp tcp | grep rfb
tcp4       0    342  subdomain.domain.rfb   p1234567-ipoe.ip.90123 ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

If `ESTABLISHED` does not appear, macOS Screensharing may be active but no users are actively viewing.

Thanks Günter Zöchbauer for the lead.

I’ll follow-up with modified Perl script.